# Telerik RadUpload.Net2 null reference when using asp:input

Tags: telerik, radupload

I've been trying to use RadUpload.Net2 from Telerik using a simple .aspx page, but i'm getting a null reference for the next line of code:

```
UploadedFile file = RadUploadContext.Current.UploadedFiles[File1.UniqueID];
```

when using the following controls:

```
<input id="File1" type="file" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Enabled="true" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
<radUpload:RadProgressManager runat="server" ID="Radprogressmanager"/>
<radUpload:RadProgressArea ID="RadProgressArea1" runat="server" />
```

I'm using IIS 7.5 with the DefaultAppPool, .Net 4.0 Integrated. The WebConfig is as follows:

```
    <configuration>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="Telerik.WebControls.RadControlsDir" value="~/Resources/RadControls/" />
    <add key="Telerik.WebControls.RadUpload.TempFolder" value="D:\Projects\ODW\Temp\Upload" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="RadUpload.Net2, Version=2.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B4E93C26A31A21F0" />
        <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
        <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages enableEventValidation="false" validateRequest="false" controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="30240" executionTimeout="10" />
    <!--<httpModules>
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadHttpModule, RadUpload.Net2, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4e93c26a31a21f0" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadProgressHandler, RadUpload.Net2, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4e93c26a31a21f0" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>-->
    <trace enabled="false" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />
    <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="RadUploadModule" type="Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadHttpModule, RadUpload.Net2, Version=2.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4e93c26a31a21f0" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="Telerik_RadUploadProgressHandler_ashx" verb="*" path="Telerik.RadUploadProgressHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.WebControls.RadUploadProgressHandler, RadUpload.Net2, Version=2.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b4e93c26a31a21f0" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The handler is registered in IIS. I've tried it on classic .Net app pools an it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RadUpload.Net2 is a very archaic control (pre-2007), you should be using the Telerik.Web.UI assembly if your project is on .NET 4

Comment: Well this is the version that I have license for. The strange thing that on a deployment, live webpage it works.I'm only having issues with it on localhost.

Comment: Try getting the files from the Request.Files collection.